# Asp.Net Core WebAPI authentication with LDAP or SAMBA

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

I have some issues with authentication and authorization in Asp.Net Core.
My aim is to use the [Authorize] attributes of Asp.Net core for controlling access to an Web API.

Unfortunately only a LDAP and SAMBA server are available for user managment. 
Is there any simple way to integrate one of these with Asp.Net Core?
Or is there any workaround, e.g. a simple OAuth 2 provider that just needs to be plugged onto LDAP or SAMBA?

I tried IdentityServer 3 and 4 but all documentation and samples have a lot of UI related code, so I cannot really find the keypoints of using it.
At the moment only a backend exists, so a sample or way to achiev this without any GUI component would be ideal.

Comment: I know there's a way to do it; did you ever figure it out?